# Обновить Cursor

Tags: android

Здравствуйте , при переходе фрагментов я сталкиваюсь с проблемой `cursor` в `CursorAdapter`  получаю ошибку

```
 Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it
```

моя идея обновить `cursor`

```
 cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(db.db.CONTENT_URI, null,
        db.db.JUST_MISSION_ID + "=" + cursor.getPosition(), null, null);

 cursor.moveToFirst()

и так вывести на первую строку но получаю следующую ошибку

Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

подскажите как правильно направить  `cursor`  на первую строку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

переменные

```
private DbHelper dbHelper;
private Cursor cursor_new;
```

в конструкторе

```
dbHelper = new DbHelper(getActivity());
```

в  onCreateView

```
    Cursor cursor = null;
    adapter = new MissionAdapter(getActivity(), cursor, Colors.getColors());

    getActivity().getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);

    String selectQuery =  "SELECT * FROM Your_DB";
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    cursor_new = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    adapter.swapCursor(cursor_new);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```